# Desktop silverlight App bluetooth and WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bluetooth

I'm new on working with Bluetooth and I need some help.

I have an application written in silverlight 4 that is running in my PC. The objective now is to get contactList or contact information from a Windows phone (Mango) via Bluetooth. I've searching the web and found no convincing answers about this. So, is it posible to obtain that information via bluetooth?? If not, is there any easy workaround??

thanks for the help

Bye,

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Use custom web server for communication between phone and PC.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Any other workaround for example with sockets?? (I've heared about them but no idea how they work)

Comment: As Ziklo says, for security means this is not possible. Not really sure but you have to write an app for the WP7 to access the Contacts data and then send it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Via bluethooth is not open is not possible as of now. May be in future if Micosoft opens the Bluetooth API's to do so, then it may be possible.

For tasks related to Bluetooth settings you can use Settings tasks with type as Bluetooth settings.